# Linking my .cs files

Tags: c#

I am trying to put some code in another .cs file since I am using
a huge switch statement and I don't want people to wade through it to
understand what is going on.  The problem is that the txtresponse
command that describes a textbox that is written to in my app is not
defined in the new file and I cannot figure out why. This is my new
file:

> (Error: txtresponse does not exist in this current context)

p.s. only using System.Windows.Forms; is highlighted it holds all the app forms,
buttons and what they do etc...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GUI_Verify
{
    class commands : Form
    {
        public static string call_command(string stmnt)
        {
            string cmd = "";
            switch (stmnt)
            {
                case "TST_ALL":
                    txtresponse.Text = "\r\nTesting all memory tests.\r\n";
                    cmd = "1";
                    break;
                case "TST_PKT_BFFR":
                    txtResponse.Text = "\r\nTest for Packet Buffer.\r\n";
                    cmd = "2";
                    break;
                case "TST_XDATA":
                    txtResponse.Text = "\r\nTest for XDATA.\r\n";
                    cmd = "3";
                    break;
                case "TST_REN_RAM":
                    txtResponse.Text = "\r\nTest for Retention Ram.\r\n";
                    cmd = "4";
                    break;
                case "TST_CODE_RAM":
                    txtResponse.Text = "\r\nTest for Code Ram.\r\n";
                    cmd = "5";
                    break;
                case "Copy_All":
                    txtResponse.Text = "\r\nCopying all memory to all places.\r\n";
                    cmd = "6";
                    break;
                case "to_xdata":
                    txtResponse.Text = "\r\nCopying xdata -> xdata.\r\n";
                    cmd = "7";
                    break;
                default:
                    txtResponse.Text = "\r\nunknown command\r\n";
                    break;
            }
            return cmd;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are inheriting the generic form, not a form that contains that textbox.

Comment: If all the switch statement does is map some strings to integers, you should look at using a dictionary

Comment: Are you sure that you want call_command to be static?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have had this problem sometime back. First comment your code and delete the txtresponse textbox in the form. Then drag n drop a new TextBox from the toolbox and rename it to "txtresponse". Uncomment your code and hopefully it should work.

**Update:**

This is just a suggestion for an alternative way. without inheriting from the Form class

Use an out put parameter to hold your value for the textbox.

```
namespace GUI_Verify
{
    public class commands
    {
        public static string call_command(string stmnt, out string result)
        {
            string cmd = "";
            switch (stmnt)
            {
                case "TST_ALL":
                    result = "\r\nTesting all memory tests.\r\n";
                    cmd = "1";
                    break;
                case "TST_PKT_BFFR":
                    result = "\r\nTest for Packet Buffer.\r\n";
                    cmd = "2";
                    break;
                case "TST_XDATA":
                    result = "\r\nTest for XDATA.\r\n";
                    cmd = "3";
                    break;
                case "TST_REN_RAM":
                    result = "\r\nTest for Retention Ram.\r\n";
                    cmd = "4";
                    break;
                case "TST_CODE_RAM":
                    result = "\r\nTest for Code Ram.\r\n";
                    cmd = "5";
                    break;
                case "Copy_All":
                    result = "\r\nCopying all memory to all places.\r\n";
                    cmd = "6";
                    break;
                case "to_xdata":
                    result = "\r\nCopying xdata -> xdata.\r\n";
                    cmd = "7";
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "\r\nunknown command\r\n";
                    break;
            }
            return cmd;
        }

    }
}
```

In your form do the following.

```
string result="";
string cmd = commands.call_command("TST_ALL", out result);
txtresponse.Text = result;
```

Comment: This has been highly unsuccessful so far sorry.

Comment: What I did to create this file was add a new cs  file, then write in that code, I have made the changes the first guy said because he is right but that didn't help.  I also tried redoing the textbox but no luck.  Is there something else I need to do

Comment: You are amazing chamara, I was getting a headache, thank you!

Comment: @Fliko Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept as the answer.